# is there a way to notify a WordPress admin when the database is changed?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

i have a WordPress site and i need to notify the admin user by an alert whenever the database is changed  ,so is it the only way to do that is using triggers or there is a better way??

Answer (score 0):

There are many options available.
You want to be notified when a post is created/updated/deleted or the whole database?
If you would like to monitor the whole database, I would rather use something db's binary log instead of triggers.

For single table, triggers are a viable option.
You could also use [save_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) hook.

Comment: actually i need to monitor one table on my database ,but i have custom operation on  my site it's not just  for adding new post or something ,and i have done some recherches about how to use triggers to call a php function to send an alert but nothing i could use,any ideas ??  @tsanecki

Comment: If you don't want to change the structure of the current table, maybe try adding a database trigger to your table, that on changes inserts to an audit table that has a sent_to_admin_flag.  Then create a PHP program that runs through all records were the flag is false and emails an admin.  Schedule the PHP to run every minute and this emails the admin with the details.  Not exactly elegant but it would work and it's not especially hard to do.